# MySQL Counts per day when count is 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a MySQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total,  DATE_FORMAT(event.serverTime,'%Y-%m-%d') AS sdate
                    FROM event
                    WHERE
                    event.serverTime >= :startDate
                    AND event.serverTime <= :endDate 
                    GROUP BY sdate;
```

Which correctly returns something like:

```
2011-08-10 => 5  
2011-08-15 => 6
```

However, I would like to also get the dates where there was 0 counts. So assuming startDate is 2011-08-10 and endDate is 2011-08-15, I would see:

```
2011-08-10 => 5  
2011-08-11 => 0  
2011-08-12 => 0  
2011-08-13 => 0  
2011-08-14 => 0  
2011-08-15 => 6
```

I am using PHP so in theory I could do some complex looping and fill up the gaps somehow, but I am wondering if there is a better solution?

Note that if no good MySQL solution exist, I'm also open to good PHP solutions

Comment: does you event table get populated when there are zero counts

Comment: no that's the issue. If there was no event for 2011-08-11, well there's just no data for that day, therefore nothing to count. I'm not even sure there is a solution to that issue...

Comment: Note that if no good MySQL solution exist, I'm also open to good PHP solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a table with dates and join against that.

```
table temp_dates
id integer auto_increment PK
mydate date  <<-- consecutive dates
```

Now do the following query

```
SELECT count(e.servertime) as total
       , td.mydate as sdate
FROM event e
RIGHT JOIN temp_dates td ON (td.mydate = date(e.servertime))
WHERE td.mydate BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate
GROUP BY td.mydate 
HAVING total = 0
```

Comment: So I would have to create a table with all the possible dates in the world?

Comment: No, only with the dates you are interested in, the dates that are in the range `BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate`

Comment: Oh actually, this exact query might work, but the issue comes if I have other "AND" statements, like "AND event.type=5", then it doesn't work anymore because it eliminates the empty rows. Maybe "HAVING" will help?

Comment: @nute, Oh you **only** want the date with 0 rows, no problem, updated the answer.

Comment: No no your query is correct, I want BOTH those with 0 and not-0. You can revert. My issue was when adding new parameters on the "event" table. I solved it by putting the conditional statements inside the ON() instead of WHERE.

Answer (score 3):

If you want count items per day with 0 result,

try this :

```
set @date_start := (SELECT MIN(date_col) FROM my_table), 
    @date_end := (SELECT MAX(date_col) FROM my_table), 
    @i := 0;
SELECT DATE(ADDDATE(@date_start, INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY)) AS date,
IFNULL((
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table AS m2
    WHERE DATE(m2.date_col) = DATE(ADDDATE(@date_start, INTERVAL @i DAY))
),0) AS total
FROM my_table AS m1
HAVING @i < DATEDIFF(@date_end, @date_start)
```

output :

```
[
    {
        "date": "2017-03-01",
        "total": "0"
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-03-02",
        "total": "0"
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-03-03",
        "total": "0"
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-03-04",
        "total": "0"
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-03-05",
        "total": "0"
    }
]
```

Comment: IMHO, this should be the correct answer.  I've revised a couple of things to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I think a possible solution you can look for is to create a table populated with all the dates and then have a join with the table.The table wont be very big as it contains just 365 rows for one year.Prepopulate this table and join with this table for your query.

The benefit here is you dont have do any complex looping of dates inside your php every time this query get called. you populated your table once and use it over and over.